# How to do a application level exception handling in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, exception

I am working on an application to do some image processing. If some thing goes wrong the application crashes. I want to avoid such scenarios. When ever any exception occurs in any stage of the application, I want to handle it and give the user a friendly message. In C#, windows form application this can be done, but for iPhone I am new and thus do not know any way of achieving it.

Can any body help me in this.

Thanks

Ashwani

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement an uncaught exception handler conforming to this signature:

```
typedef volatile void NSUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception);
```

by calling the `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` function. From there you can popup whatever UI you want to inform the user that the app is shutting down (we actually collect a stack trace and invoke a mailto: url to have the crash sent to us--this is obsolete given iTunes 8.2's automatic crash reporting).

EDIT:
To be clear, your app **will** be terminated after your handler is finished, there's no way around it. I'm not sure why you would want your app to continue execution at this point, given that it's very likely in an inconsistent state. It's almost always better to just let it crash than to potentially corrupt data or worse. From the Apple docs:

> Sets the top-level error-handling
>   function where you can perform
>   last-minute logging before the program
>   **terminates**.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But can u please tell me where I have to put this NSUncaughtExceptionHandler? In the appdelegate file or some where else?

Comment: I was able to use the function. I am able to display user a friendly message but application is crashing also. I do not want the application the application to crash. Can this be done??

Answer (score 1):

```
void UncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
   @try
{
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Committed Suicide"
                                                    message:@"Oh dear, that wasn't supposed to happen. You will have to restart the application... sorry!"
                                                   delegate:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"That's ok!", @"Erm, bye...", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    while (exceptionAlertDismissed == FALSE)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{

}
@finally
{
    @throw exception;
}
}
```

The above method is a delegate method of **NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler** which is a class to caught the exception  and
 **write the above method in appDelegate class .m file** and add the statement
**NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler (&UncaughtExceptionHandler);** in
  **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method
Any exception which was occurred in your view controller the above delegate method will called and shows the Alert Message.

Thank You

Comment: method is called but not display alertview

Comment: @PramodTapaniya, may be it's because of [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertview) is deprecated. Use [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller) instead.

Comment: Is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" get cought in this method. I tryed but this method is not getting called. As far as I know sign sighandler is required for this memory related crash issue. Any idea how we can cought this  "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"